# SSRS - Group Header will not repeat on the top of each page

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have read every post i could find regarding this issue and had no luck. I would like the County, Status, ID and Name rows to repeat on each page. I have reformatted the report since my original post but it's still not working.  There is a parent group (County), with 1 child group (status).  The status group contains the details. The attached images display the current settings.  I thought this configuration would work according to other posts i have read but it's not working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
[image: Parent Group]

[image: Status Child Group]

[image: Id/Name Row]

Comment: could it be because the parent group is grouped by 2 fields (county then status)?  I will try to creating a child group for status after county.

Comment: creating 2 separate groups did not fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I removed the existing tablix and created a new one with the same grouping and setting and it rendered correctly, repeating the headers as desired.